# MySQL WHERE IN wildcard

Tags: mysql, where-clause

First of all, I know that the `downloads` table is not normalized.

I have those two tables:

```
downloads

map | author
1 | Nikola
2 | Nikola George
```

and

```
mappers

mapper_id | mapper_name
1 | Nikola
2 | George
```

I want to find all possible download rows a given user is to be found by his ID.

What I've done is:

```
SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE author IN (SELECT mapper_name FROM mappers WHERE mapper_id = '1')
```

But that would return me only the maps which are done only by userid: 1 (in that case Nikola) and co-maps wouldn't show.

My goal is: searching for ID: 1 both map #1 and map #2 are returned, searching for mapper id #2 - map #2 is returned

Comment: I would recommend you to create a FK in the Downloads table with PK in mappers

Comment: You can do a join in FIND_IN_SET. Normally this is used for comma separated lists, but you can do a replace of space for comma to still use it. Not likely to be efficient though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment, something like this can be used if you cannot normalise your data

```
SELECT * 
FROM downloads 
INNER JOIN mappers
ON FIND_IN_SET(mappers.mapper_name, REPLACE(downloads.author, " ", ",")) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select 
from downloads d join
     mappers m
     on concat(' ', d.author, ' ') like concat('% ', m.mapper_name, ' %')
where m.id = 1
```

This is not efficient, but it does meet your need.